# started getting ?? after . at the end of the sentence

Tags: fonts, encoding, embedded-fonts

Just started getting emails from folks about my Emails showing ?? after the end of the sentence period.  I usually put a period at the end of the sentence and then put two spaces before starting the next sentence.  My setting in Advance formatting option was:

Fonts for Latin
Text Encoding set at UTF-8

Changed to Fonts being Other Writing Systems (as I don't see US English) and text encoding to Western (Windows-1252).

Still the same issue with, but just one ? after the period when the email is received by anyone.

Any guidance?

Thank you all.

Comment: Which email client and operating system? Perhaps you have a strange character in there?